# Access exact page break via lualatex

Tags: luatex, page-breaking, atbegshi

I have a journal layout where the first page (with the article title) has an odd 1.5 column layout. The first column which holds the meta data is narrower than the right column with the first few paragraphs of the main text. From the second page, the layout is an even two-column layout where both columns are equally sized.

I achieve that by defining a macro `\@output@first@dblcol` that forks LaTeX kernel's `\@outputdblcol` for the first page and switching back to the kernel definiton after the title page using the `\AtBeginShipoutNext` hook from the `atbegshi` package unless the author/editor has set the page break by hand.

The whole source code for a MWE is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}

\textwidth124mm
\columnwidth60mm
\columnsep4mm

\author{Max Mustermann*, John Doe}
\title{Test document with a longer title}

\makeatletter
\let\ltx@outputdblcol\@outputdblcol
\def\@output@first@dblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global\@firstcolumnfalse
    \global\setbox\@leftcolumn\copy\@outputbox
    \splitmaxdepth\maxdimen
    \vbadness\maxdimen
     \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\unvbox\@outputbox\unskip}%
     \setbox\@outputbox\vsplit\@outputbox to\maxdimen
    \toks@\expandafter{\topmark}%
    \xdef\@firstcoltopmark{\the\toks@}%
    \toks@\expandafter{\splitfirstmark}%
    \xdef\@firstcolfirstmark{\the\toks@}%
    \ifx\@firstcolfirstmark\@empty
      \global\let\@setmarks\relax
    \else
      \gdef\@setmarks{%
        \let\firstmark\@firstcolfirstmark
        \let\topmark\@firstcoltopmark}%
    \fi
  \else
    \global\@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{%
     \hb@xt@\textwidth{%
        \hb@xt@40mm{\box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
        {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
        \hfil
        \hb@xt@80mm{\box\@outputbox \hss}}}%
  \@combinedblfloats
    \@setmarks
    \@outputpage
    \begingroup
      \@dblfloatplacement
      \@startdblcolumn
      \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi{\@outputpage
     \@startdblcolumn}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}%

\def\maketitle{%
  \let\is@firstpage\relax
  \let\@outputdblcol\@output@first@dblcol
  \twocolumn[{\bfseries\large\@author}\par\vskip10bp{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\@title}\vskip18bp]%
  \par
  \bgroup
    \raggedright
    \hsize40mm
    \parindent\z@
    \textbf{Email:} mustermann@example.org\par
    \textbf{Max Mustermann:} University of Life\par
    \textbf{Abtract:} \lipsum*[1][1-3]\par
  \egroup
  \newpage
  \hsize80mm
  }

\def\titlebreak{%
  \ifhmode\vadjust{\par\newpage\noindent}\else\newpage\fi%
  \global\let\@outputdblcol\ltx@outputdblcol
  \global\let\is@firstpage\@undefined
  \global\columnwidth60mm
  \global\hsize\columnwidth
  \global\linewidth\columnwidth
}
\AtBeginShipoutNext{\ifx\is@firstpage\relax\titlebreak\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-3]

\lipsum[4-9]
\end{document}
```

with the output being
[image: output of MWE]

As you can see, this works pretty well, except for the remainder of the paragraph where the page break occurs. If the first page break occurs within a paragraph, authors/editors are told to set the `\titlebreak` macro by hand in the line with the page break.

But I was wondering if there is a way to automate that first page break using LuaLaTeX?

**Question**: Is there a way (a lua hook, maybe) that allows me to automatically inject the `\titlebreak` macro at the precise point (or line) where LuaLaTeX breaks the page? How would I implement that in my existing code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use a simplified MWE here to make the effect easier to see:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\AddToHookNext{shipout}{%
    \global\columnwidth=0.5\columnwidth
    \global\textwidth=\columnwidth
    \global\hsize=\columnwidth
    \AddToHookNext{shipout}{%
        \global\columnwidth=2\columnwidth
        \global\textwidth=\columnwidth
        \global\hsize=\columnwidth
    }
}

\newdimen\bigright \bigright=\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+\textwidth\relax
\newdimen\smallright \smallright=\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+0.5\textwidth\relax

\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
    \put(\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in, 0in){%
        \line(0,-1){\paperheight}
    }%
    \put(\bigright, 0in){%
        \line(0,-1){\paperheight}
    }%
    \put(\smallright, 0in){%
        \line(0,-1){\paperheight}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image: original output]

You should be able to use any other way of changing the page layout here; the key thing is that you need to set the column width for the next page *before* the previous page is shipped out. This also means that this solution will only adjust the width of the first column on each page, so the columns on any given page must all have the same width.

> Is there a way (a lua hook, maybe) that allows me to automatically inject the `\titlebreak` macro at the precise point (or line) where LuaLaTeX breaks the page?

Not really. Paragraph breaking happens strictly before (or parallel to) page breaking, so when the paragraph is made it cannot "know" where or if it will be split across a page.

With traditional TeX methods, you could define a macro to have the paragraph write out its split point to the `.aux` file on the first run, then use `\parshape` trickery to make correctly size the paragraph on the second run. This would be fairly tedious though, and I'm not too sure how well it would work.

The other option is to use some Lua trickery. Before each paragraph is broken, we can mark each node (glyphs + glue + etc.) with an attribute and save a copy. Then when the output routine is triggered, we can look though `contrib_head` (any paragraphs held over until the next page), match up the broken nodes with the pre-broken nodes, and replace the paragraph with a freshly-broken correctly-sized paragraph. The only tricky thing here is that there's no `post_output_filter`, so we need to actually run this before shipout instead of after the output routine.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\csname @ifl@t@r\endcsname\fmtversion{2020-10-01}{}{
    % TL2019 compatibility
    \usepackage{atbegshi}

    \directlua{luatexbase.create_callback("pre_shipout_filter", "list", false)}
    \AtBeginShipout{%
        \csname columns@run\endcsname
        \directlua{luatexbase.call_callback("pre_shipout_filter", tex.box.AtBeginShipoutBox)}%
    }

    \usepackage{picture}
    \def\AddToHookNext#1#2{
        \global\expandafter\def\csname columns@run\endcsname{#2}
    }
    \def\AddToHook#1#2{\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{#2}}}
}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/firstpage}{%
    \global\columnwidth=0.5\columnwidth
    \global\textwidth=\columnwidth
    \global\hsize=\columnwidth
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/before}{%
        \global\columnwidth=2\columnwidth
        \global\textwidth=\columnwidth
        \global\hsize=\columnwidth
    }
}

\newdimen\bigright \bigright=\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+\textwidth\relax
\newdimen\smallright \smallright=\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+0.5\textwidth\relax

\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
    \put(\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in, 0in){%
        \line(0,-1){\paperheight}
    }%
    \put(\bigright, 0in){%
        \line(0,-1){\paperheight}
    }%
    \put(\smallright, 0in){%
        \line(0,-1){\paperheight}
    }%
}


\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
-- Save some LuaTeX internal node functions
local copy_list = node.copy_list
local find_attribute = node.find_attribute
local get_attribute = node.get_attribute
local has_attribute = node.has_attribute
local set_attribute = node.set_attribute
local slide = node.slide
local traverse = node.traverse
local traverse_list = node.traverse_list


-- Define some module-global variables
local attr = luatexbase.new_attribute("mark_paragraph")
local count = 1
local saved = node.new("glue")
local columnwidth = 0


-- Mark each node in a paragraph and save the pre-broken tagged contents
local function save_paragraph(head)
    for n in traverse(head) do
        set_attribute(n, attr, count)
        count = count + 1
    end

    slide(saved).next = copy_list(head)
    columnwidth = tex.dimen.columnwidth

    return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", save_paragraph, "save_paragraph")


-- Fix the width of any partial paragraphs carried over from the previous page
local function fix_paragraph(head)
    -- do nothing if columnwidth has not been changed
    if columnwidth == tex.dimen.columnwidth then return true end

    -- do nothing if the last contribution is a penalty, meaning that the page break was forced manually 
    if tex.lists.contrib_head.id == 14 then return true end

    local first_index, first_n, first_list
    local last_index, last_n, last_list

    for list, _, _, inner in traverse_list(tex.lists.contrib_head) do
        if not first_index then
            first_index = find_attribute(inner, attr)
            first_list = list
        end

        local prev_last_index
        local m = inner
        repeat
            last_index = prev_last_index
            prev_last_index, m = find_attribute(m.next, attr)
        until (not prev_last_index) or (not m.next)
        last_list = list
    end

    for n in traverse(saved) do
        if not first_n and
           (get_attribute(n, attr) or 0) >= first_index
        then
            first_n = n
        end

        if has_attribute(n, attr, last_index) then
            last_n = n
            break
        end
    end

    first_n.prev.next = nil
    node.flush_list(saved)
    saved = node.new("glue")

    local new = copy_list(first_n, last_n.next)
    local broken = tex.linebreak(new)
    first_list.prev.next = broken
    slide(broken).next = last_list.next

    last_list.next = nil
    node.flush_list(first_list)

    return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_shipout_filter", fix_paragraph, "fix_paragraph")
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
    \Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image: solution output]

There's probably still a few bugs, but this seemed to work okay in my testing.

Comment: This works well for TL2022, so I'll grant the bounty. Unfortunately, for other reasons, I stuck with TL2019 for the moment, and back then, `pre_shipout_filter` didn't exist. `pre_output_filter` doesn't work because `tex.lists.contrib_head` is handled differently and the first loop in the `fix_paragraph` method isn't traversed, at all. But thanks for the answer, now I have a starting point to dig deeper from.

Comment: @Lupino I've edited the answer to add TL2019 compatibility.

Comment: @Lupino `contrib_head` should be identical between `pre_shipout_filter` and `pre_output_filter`; the reason why switching it doesn't work is because `pre_output_filter` is called before the output routine, so the `\columnwidth` hasn't changed yet. You could replace the `if columnwidth ~= …` check with a custom \newif that you'd need to set every time before you want to change the column width, but for a more general solution I've added a (very fragile!) definition of `pre_shipout_filter`.

Comment: Note: I had to insert another `if first_index then` before `for n in traverse(saved) do` until the `return true` for cases where the page brake coincides with a par break.

Comment: two more changes: The first `\AddToHookNext` requires another parameter in its first argument with TL2020 and newer; "shipout" alone is not sufficient For my purpose `shipout/firstpage` was ideal. (and it won't disturb TL2019, since the argument is gobbled there.) 

The thing with the coincidental pagebreak I mentioned in my last comment, I now solved with a line `if tex.lists.contrib_head.id == 14 then return true end` at the very beginning of the `fix_paragraph()` function.

Comment: @Lupino Thanks for finding those bugs! Could you please edit those changes into the answer so that no one accidentally copies my broken version?

Comment: done. There is still an issue that if the page break coincides with a section heading that does not fit on the bottom of the first page with the next two lines of the next paragraph, I get a wired issue that the heading is placed on the second page and the text starts on the same line but moved to the right. But at least the column width is as it should, for both the paragraph and the section. If i set a `\newpage` before the heading, everything works fine.

Comment: Another issue is that this mechanism destroys the prevdepth of the paragraph that is broken onto the second page. The next paragraph starts a `\dp\strutbox` higher than when I break the paragraph "by hand" if the last line of that broken paragraph has no underlengths. -.-